# SQL Server : full text search

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I was trying to setup the full text search on a table.

Below is Script to repro my issue:

Creating table:

```
create table dbo.articles 
(
    id int identity(1, 1) not null,
    title varchar(255),
    content varchar(max)
);
```

Adding the primary key constraint:

```
alter table dbo.articles   
    add constraint PK_articles primary key clustered (id);
```

Inserting data into the table:

```
insert into dbo.articles (title, content)
    select 
        'DBA presents - Testing T-SQL script before execution', bulkcolumn
    from 
        OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\DBA\Files\MySQL Administrator Bible.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
```

Create catalog:

```
create fulltext catalog DbaPresentsArticles;
```

Create index:

```
create fulltext index 
     on dbo.articles (title language 1033,
                      content language 1033)
     key index PK_articles on DbaPresentsArticles
     with change_tracking auto;
```

Running select statement:

```
select *
from dbo.articles
where contains(content, 'replication');
```

This select statement is returning the same result when I run the simple select statement on table without any condition:
[image]

Comment: `This select statement is returning the same result when I run the simple select statement on table without any condition: ` what do you expect to be returned

Comment: As I created full text index on table i am expecting it to return the data which i included in where condition not full data.